# PosExplorer().getDevices returning null in .Net applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, pos-for-.net

I am developing billing app using .Net. I need to print receipt using EPSON TM-T81. I have installed all required drivers and MS POS v1.12. I can successfully print sample content through CheckHealth Utility. So looks there is no issue in PosPrinter configuration. But still PosExplorer().getDevices returning null value. I tried both in windows and ASP.Net application but still the same issue.
Code:
PosPrinter m_Printer = null;

```
        //<<<step1>>>--Start
        //Use a Logical Device Name which has been set on the SetupPOS.
        string strLogicalName = "PosPrinter";
        try
        {
            //Create PosExplorer
            PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();

            DeviceInfo deviceInfo = null;

            try
            {
                deviceInfo = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter,strLogicalName);
                m_Printer =(PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                ChangeButtonStatus();
                return;
            }

            //Open the device
            m_Printer.Open();

            //Get the exclusive control right for the opened device.
            //Then the device is disable from other application.
            m_Printer.Claim(1000);

            //Enable the device.
            m_Printer.DeviceEnabled = true;
        }
        catch(PosControlException)
        {
            ChangeButtonStatus();
        }
        //<<<step1>>>--End
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is exactly the code you're trying to run, then the problem is that strLogicalName does not contain a valid SO or logical device name. That "PosPrinter" is simply a placehoder in the code sample (unless you explicitly set up such a logical name, of course).

In order to find out SO names/logical device names available in your system use these commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Point Of Service\posdm.exe" listdevices /type:PosPrinter

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Point Of Service\posdm.exe" listnames /type:PosPrinter
```